# Unable to get captured group value

Tags: c#, regex

This is how my Input looks like:

```
"A1-BC-12345-D2"
```

This is how my regex expression looks like. It takes everything between last - and one before it:

```
"([^-]+)(?=-[^-]+-?$)"
```

I am trying capture 12345 in a variable without loop:

This is how my code looks like:

```
string output = Regex.Replace("A1-BC-12345-D2", @"([^-]+)(?=-[^-]+-?$)", "$1");
```

output looks same as input.

I have verified the regex on regex101.com and it is capturing the right values.

How do i get 12345 in the output using capture group?

### Edit

I cannot use `Match` or loop through as I am trying to use this in AD FS Claims Rule which only supports `Replace`

Comment: Why do you use `Replace` when you want to `Match`?

Comment: because i am trying to use this in AD FS Claims Rules which only supports replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can only use a replace, then you should modify your regex so that it selects everything you don't want, and then puts the things to do want in a capture group. Then use the replacement string to keep the capture groups intact (as you did).

```
^.*?([^-]+)-[^-]+-?$
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tU2cB1/2)

```
string output = Regex.Replace("A1-BC-12345-D2", @"^.*?([^-]+)-[^-]+-?$", "$1");
```

Comment: It works but if i want to get $2 in there, it again breaks if i try to create a group.

Comment: What are you putting the group around?

Comment: here is the regex101 example: https://regex101.com/r/eM6cP7/1. In there i need new in $1 and year in $2

Comment: You forgot to add the `^.*?` to the beginning, and also there's no need for a look-ahead if the characters are going to be matched immediately after. Here's the updated regex: https://regex101.com/r/eM6cP7/2

Comment: you are genius, my friend.